# React Native - setState doesn't work in constructor

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here is my code:

I want to set functions results which I get them as promises to some **state** variables but as it seems after use **this.setState** in then() function it returns empty object!
I checked in then() block and it contains data as it's supposed to.

```
class ProfileScreen extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            profile_data: {},
            user_data: {}
        };

        this._getUserData().then(response => {
            this.setState({user_data: response});
        });
        //Empty Results
        console.log(this.state.user_data);

        this._getProfileData(this.state.user_data.id).then(response => {
            this.setState({profile_data: response});
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all **you should never set your state in constructor using setState**  as a call to `setState` leads to rerendering of the view heirarchy which is not yet built to be rerendered.

A better place for doing so is `componentDidMount` because thats a lifecycle callback which ensures that the DOM is already rendered once and now you can update your state to see the changes in the view.

Coming to your problem, the empty result is due to the fact that the `setState` is asynchronous in nature, thus the `console.log` would have run even before the setState has updated the state.

You should rely on the second parameter of the `setState` which is a callback that runs post the state update.

```
this.setState({
   user_data: response
}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.user_data);
})
```

> **Don't do this in your constructor. Fetch your user detail in `componentDidMount` and then set your state as per your need**

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Suraj said, if `_getUserData` is asynchronous, perhaps doing an AJAX call, then `_getProfileData` must be inside the `.then` callback too since you depend on the `user_data` to fetch the `profile_data`.

Try this snack out: https://snack.expo.io/@transfusion/stackoverflow-53694220

It might be cleaner to just chain the promises together.